# migrating parse-server / mlab deployment to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, parse-server, mlab

I originally posted this question on ServerFault, but it didn't get any traction, so I thought that stack might be a better forum for this question. My apologies if this out of line.

We are currently running parse-server (v2.7.2) on Heroku (node.js 7.10.1), connected to an mLab mongodb database.  I recently received a notification 
from mLab that they have been acquired by MongoDB and will be eventually migrating all customers to MongoDB Atlas.

The migration instructions from mLab to Atlas seem fairly self explanatory.  My question concerns parse-server itself:

Does our version of parse-server (2.7.2) and node.js (7.10.1) have drivers that will support Atlas MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB feature compatibility will depend on the underlying driver version which you can find by running `npm list mongodb` in the directory where you installed `parse-server`.

You can also check the `mongodb` driver version requested in `parse-server`'s `package.json`, but a newer driver version may be installed depending on the semver notation used.

It looks like [parse-server 2.7.2 uses the `mongodb` 3.0.1 driver](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/2.7.2/package.json#L34), which is fully compatible with MongoDB 3.4 and 3.6 features according to the [MongoDB Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility) documentation.

The MongoDB Node 3.0.x driver won't support newer features of MongoDB 4.0 (for example, transactions), but you should otherwise be fine with an Atlas deployment using MongoDB 3.4 or newer.